# Active record association works only in one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've a problem with an active record relation. I have a Content class and a Product Class defined in this way:

```
Class Content < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many                :product_relations, as:         :productable
  has_many                :products,          through:    :product_relations

end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

`Content.first.products` return me the products associated to the contents, but I cannot create an association to build a query like `Product.first.contents` that return me all the contents associated to a product.

**Update**

I have also this class:

```
class ProductRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :productable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Solved**

```
has_many :contents, through: :product_relations, source_type: "Content", source: :productable
```